# I have errors with this File Input/Output. I have exactly 100 errors

Tags: java, file, input, error-handling, output

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BLLElgaMain extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener{

Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Acer\\Documents\\JCreator LE\\MyProjects\\ELGA PROJECT\\Items.txt"));

int total=0, cash=0, price=0, change=0, allinall=0, hmany=0;
String output2="";
int height=0;
int choice=0, edit=0, choicedelete=0, changee=0;
int customer=0;

//item code variables :)
int itemcode1,itemcode2,itemcode3,itemcode4,itemcode5,itemcode6,itemcode7,itemcode8,itemcode9,itemcode10;
int itemcode11,itemcode12,itemcode13,itemcode14,itemcode15,itemcode16,itemcode117,itemcode18,itemcode19,itemcode20;
int itemcode21,itemcode22,itemcode23,itemcode24,itemcode25;

//item name variables :)
String itemname1,itemname2,itemname3,itemname4,itemname5,itemname6,itemname7,itemname8,itemname9,itemname10;
String itemname11,itemname1,itemname13,itemname14,itemname15,itemname16,itemname17,itemname18,itemname19,itemname20;
String itemname21,itemname22,itemname23,itemname24,itemname25;

//itemstock variables :)
int itemstock1,itemstock2,itemstock3,itemstock4,itemstock5,itemstock6,itemstock7,itemstock8,itemstock9,itemstock10;
int itemstock11,itemstock12,itemstock13,itemstock14,itemstock15,itemstock16,itemstock17,itemstock18,itemstock19,itemstock20;
int itemstock21,itemstock22,itemstock23,itemstock24,itemstock25;

//itemprice variables :)
double itemprice1,itemprice2,itemprice3,itemprice4,itemprice5,itemprice6,itemprice7,itemprice8,itemprice9,itemprice10;
double itemprice11,itemprice12,itemprice13,itemprice14,itemprice15,itemprice16,itemprice17,itemprice18,itemprice19,itemprice20;
double itemprice21,itemprice22,itemprice23,itemprice24,itemprice25;
// --------------------------------------
//Albums
//mama album
itemcode1 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname1 = inFile.next();
itemstock1 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice1 = inFile.nextDouble();

//1st box album
itemcode2 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname2 = inFile.next();
itemstock2 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice2 = inFile.nextDouble();

//growl album
itemcode3 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname3 = inFile.next();
itemstock3 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice3 = inFile.nextDouble();

//xoxo album
itemcode4 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname4 = inFile.next();
itemstock4 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice4 = inFile.nextDouble();

//mid album
itemcode5 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname5 = inFile.next();
itemstock5 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice5 = inFile.nextDouble();

// --------------------------------------
//Shirts
//wolf 88
itemcode6 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname6 = inFile.next();
itemstock6 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice6 = inFile.nextDouble();

//xoxo
itemcode7 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname7 = inFile.next();
itemstock7 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice7 = inFile.nextDouble();

//growl
itemcode8 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname8 = inFile.next();
itemstock8 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice8 = inFile.nextDouble();

//bwcw
itemcode9 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname9 = inFile.next();
itemstock9 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice9 = inFile.nextDouble();

//wolf 88
itemcode10 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname10 = inFile.next();
itemstock10 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice10 = inFile.nextDouble();

// --------------------------------------
//Accessories
//baller
itemcode11 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname11 = inFile.next();
itemstock11 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice11 = inFile.nextDouble();

//bracelet
itemcode12 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname12 = inFile.next();
itemstock12 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice12 = inFile.nextDouble();

//ring
itemcode13 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname13 = inFile.next();
itemstock13 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice13 = inFile.nextDouble();

//cap
itemcode14 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname14 = inFile.next();
itemstock14 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice14 = inFile.nextDouble();

//beanie
itemcode15 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname15 = inFile.next();
itemstock15 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice15 = inFile.nextDouble();

// --------------------------------------
//Bags
//From EXO Planet backpack with chibis
itemcode16 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname16 = inFile.next();
itemstock16 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice16 = inFile.nextDouble();

//EXO Backpack
itemcode17 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname17 = inFile.next();
itemstock17 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice17 = inFile.nextDouble();

//Overdose tote-bag
itemcode18 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname18 = inFile.next();
itemstock18 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice18 = inFile.nextDouble();

//Exo chibi tote-bag
itemcode19 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname19 = inFile.next();
itemstock19 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice19 = inFile.nextDouble();

//From EXO Planet tote-bag
itemcode20 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname20 = inFile.next();
itemstock20 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice20 = inFile.nextDouble();

// --------------------------------------
//Shoes
//XOXO High-Cut
itemcode21 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname21 = inFile.next();
itemstock21 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice21 = inFile.nextDouble();

//XOXO with Chibi High-Cut
itemcode22 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname22 = inFile.next();
itemstock22 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice22 = inFile.nextDouble();

//EXO Galaxy High-Cut
itemcode23 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname23 = inFile.next();
itemstock23 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice23 = inFile.nextDouble();

//EXO Vans inspired
itemcode24 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname24 = inFile.next();
itemstock24 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice24 = inFile.nextDouble();

//Wolf 88 High-Cut
itemcode25 = inFile.nextInt();
itemname25 = inFile.next();
itemstock25 = inFile.nextInt();
itemprice25 = inFile.nextDouble();

/*.
.
.
.
.
.this section includes the complete body of my code
.
.
*/
public static void main(String args[])
{
    JDialog.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    new BLLElgaMain();
    inFile.close();
}
}}
```

My problem is... I have 100 errors and which my only error of my program is:

```
  C:\Users\Acer\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\ELGA PROJECT\BLLElgaMain.java:211: error: <identifier> expected
itemprice25 = inFile.nextDouble();
```

Guide me for my codes please :( and also say anything if I did wrong on this post/questio. Thank you :)
Please help me :( Thank you very much again :)

Comment: Methods are your friends

Comment: Indeed - basically you've put all your code directly into the class. You can't do that - you need to create *methods* and put the code in there. Classes can only contain methods, field declarations, constructors, and nested types.

Comment: What am i gonna do? :(

Comment: Consider reading a Java tutorial.

Comment: You are trying coding :(

Comment: `"I have exactly 100 errors"` -- When you've got multiple errors like this, this suggests that your style of coding perhaps needs to be fixed. Don't type a large amount of code and then test it. Instead if you can't use a modern IDE such as NetBeans or Eclipse (which warns you of compilation issues almost immediately), then it is up to you to compile your code **early and often**, and most importantly **to not add any new code until current compilation issues are fixed**. Else you'll end up with a rat's nest of hard to fix errors.

Comment: user never came back ... too broad in the first place ... could/should be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I edited my code and I now have 1 error left XD

It's all about... putting throws FileNotFoundException